# electromagnetic waves: $ f(t) = A \sin(Bt) $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, wavelength

I recently saw this question which was slightly lacking in formulation, but I was still interested in solving it; but I can't.

> Light can be seen as electromagnetic waves, which in vacuum, moves with the speed of $3\times 10^8\ \text{m/s}$. The waves can be described using the formula: $f(t)=A \sin(Bt)$. What is the value of $B$ for blue light with the estimated wavelength of $450\ \text{nm}$ and yellow light with the estimated wavelength of $580\ \text{nm}$?

I tried using the standard wavelength equation, but fell short.

Comment: cross posted from [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139451).

Comment: A wave is not described by such formulation - only the electrical field at one point in the wave might be. A more usual formulation would be $E=A\sin(\omega t - kx)$ which shows that both frequency and wavelength matter for a wave. These are of course related through the wave speed. $k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$, $\omega = 2\pi f$ and $\lambda f = c$, the speed of light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation of a plane wave is:

$$ \psi(x,t) = A e ^{i(kx - \omega t)} $$

where $k$ is the [wave number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) and $\omega$ is the [angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency):

$$\begin{align}
k &= \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \\
\omega &= 2\pi\nu
\end{align}$$

Your equation is presumably assuming constant $x$ and measuring the variation only wih time. In that case the constant $B$ is the angular frequency so you just need to calculate the frequency from the supplied wavelength and multiply by $2\pi$.